# What is the best way in python to download data using an .atomscv file?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have an .atomsvc file, which I can open in Power BI to download the linked data, but I'd like to automate the process in Python directly.

The data when loaded in Power BI looks like
[image: Data from .atomsvc file as viewed in Power BI]

The .atomsvc file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"><workspace><atom:title>[NMDS][Station][Detail]SingleDayByStation</atom:title><collection href="http://sql-2/ReportServer?%2Ftdms.reports%2F%5BNMDS%5D%5BStation%5D%5BDetail%5DSingleDayByStation&amp;Header=Massachusetts%20Highway%20Department&amp;TitleAndCriteria=Counts%20by%20Station&amp;Footer=&amp;AgencyId=96&amp;StartDate=01%2F01%2F2022%2000%3A00%3A00&amp;EndDate=12%2F31%2F2022%2000%3A00%3A00&amp;LocationSetId=2757120&amp;ReportLocationSetId=5211&amp;rs%3AParameterLanguage=&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3AItemPath=Tablix6.Subreport1.Tablix3.Offset.Pathway.Mode.Direction"><atom:title>Tablix6</atom:title></collection></workspace></service>
```

Ideally, I am looking to open the .atomscv file and save the data to a Pandas DataFrame or similar to be able to work with the data.

```py
df = read_atomscv('file.atomscv')
```

I haven't found any modules that seem to do this directly. I've tried feedparser and (XMLParser and XMLPullParser from) xml.etree.ElementTree, but haven't figured out how to actually download data with either method.

```py
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('path_to_file.atomscv')
```

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser, XMLPullParser
parser = XMLParser()
parser.feed('path_to_file.atomscv')

parser2 = XMLPullParser()
parser2.feed('path_to_file.atomscv')
```

I've attempted to start making my own function to do this, but run into issues getting requests to communicate with the site.

```py
output = request.get(url_from_atomscv_file)
```

yields `Exception has occurred: ConnectionError HTTPConnectionPool(host='sql-2', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:[...]`

Attempting to make a session with the site where I downloaded the .atomscv file from before was not more productive

```py
session_url = 'https://mhd.ms2soft.com/tdms.ui/nmds/analysis?loc=mhd'
session = requests.Session()
session_response = session.get(session_url)
print(session_response.raise_for_status())
raw = session.get(url_from_atomscv_file)
```

prints `None` for the status and yields the same exception as above.

Is there a better way to interact with this file/data source?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I tested you link `https://mhd.ms2soft.com/tdms.ui/nmds/analysis?loc=mhd` and it shows some page but I don't see any file to download. Maybe it needs to login.